# Can you increase the visual size of a flash cs3 Checkbox Component?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I want to use the checkbox component in my flash app, but it's really tiny.  According to this article [1](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000504.html), the size and scale parameters only affect the invisible bounding box.  Does anyone know of a quick solution on how to scale up (enlarge) the visual area of the checkbox component in flash CS3?

Answer (score 2):

I solve the problem by copy checkbox inside a movieclip and then resizing the movie clip.

Answer (score 2):

After you have added the CheckBox component, go to the library and open the folder 'Component Assets.' Locate the folder 'CheckBoxSkins' and edit every item to the size, color, etc. that you require.

You only have to do the 'tick' (CheckBox_selectedIcon) once as it is used with all the state boxes.

Scaling or sizing in the code does not work.

For my application, which was visual, I created 2 graphics for selected and unselected, added them to stage 'addChild();' and used 'visible' to show or hide them within an if{} function.

For example,

```
if(condition is true){
    checkboxUnselected.visible = true;
    checkboxSelected.visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the entire component with `myCheckBox._xscale=200;myCheckBox._yscale=200;`
However this will scale *everything*, including the line thicknesses, text size, shadow etc, so it might not be the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Hi Ricard,

I should have specified that I'm using AS3, which uses .scaleX as opposed to ._xscale.  Regardless, when I use these and the .setSize command, I'm only affecting the invisible bounding box and not the visible size of the checkbox.